# Finding integrator

Tags: analysis

I am currently studying Riemann Stieltjes integrals and I am stuck on understanding the following:
$\int_a^bfd\alpha=f(c_1)+5f(c_2)+12f(c_3)+1/2\int_c^df(x)dx$ implies that $\alpha$ has jump discontinuities at $c_1,c_2,c_3$wtih values $1,5,12$.

Could someone please explain me why and also how can one find $\alpha$ from this equation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the assumption holds for continuous functions $f$ only. Also, is $\alpha$ right-continuous? I suppose so.

Anyway, I would work backwards. First, introduce function $\beta$ with slope $1/2$ on the interval $[c,d]$ (to reproduce $(1/2)\int_c^d f(x)\,dx$ part) and add jumps at the appropriate points. Using the Heaviside function notation and $x^+=\max(x,0)$ notation, you should get 
$$\beta(x)=H(x-c_1)+5H(x-c_2)+12H(x-c_3)+\frac{1}{2}(x-c)^+$$

The final step is to argue that since $\int f\,d(\alpha-\beta)$ is zero for all continuous functions $f$, the function $\alpha-\beta$ must be constant. (Assuming it takes distinct values at two points, cook up a function whose integral is nonzero). Note that the above does not determine $\alpha$ completely: from the integral you can find it only up to an additive constant.